# Get a cumulative sum in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

I am struggling with a postgresql query where I am trying to get the cumulative sum instead of the sum, by date truncated.

Here is my original query

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', "public"."stock_transaction"."created_at") AS "created_at", "Category"."name" AS "Category - name", sum("public"."stock_transaction"."cost") AS "sum"
FROM "public"."stock_transaction"
LEFT JOIN "public"."product" "Product" ON "public"."stock_transaction"."product_id" = "Product"."id" LEFT JOIN "public"."category" "Category" ON "Product"."category_id" = "Category"."id"
WHERE ("public"."stock_transaction"."owner_id" = {{organization.id}}::uuid
   AND {{createdAt}}
   AND "Product"."recipe" = FALSE)
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', "public"."stock_transaction"."created_at"), "Category"."name"
ORDER BY date_trunc('month', "public"."stock_transaction"."created_at") ASC, "Category"."name" ASC
```

and it looks like this

[image: chart picture]

It's generated by metabase. createdAt is a date field filter and organizationId an uuid.

The result should be an increasing bar chart with the value of each month added to the previous month.

I have tried with subqueries but I have a hard time solving every SQL error I jump into.

Is there a SQL boss around who can help? Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

you just need a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to get a cumulative sum :

```
SELECT s."created_at"
     , s."Category - name"
     , sum(s."sum") OVER (PARTITION BY s."created_at", s."Category - name" ORDER BY s."created_at" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS "sum"
FROM (
SELECT date_trunc('month', "public"."stock_transaction"."created_at") AS "created_at", "Category"."name" AS "Category - name", sum("public"."stock_transaction"."cost") AS "sum"
FROM "public"."stock_transaction"
LEFT JOIN "public"."product" "Product" ON "public"."stock_transaction"."product_id" = "Product"."id" 
LEFT JOIN "public"."category" "Category" ON "Product"."category_id" = "Category"."id"
WHERE ("public"."stock_transaction"."owner_id" = {{organization.id}}::uuid
  AND {{createdAt}}
  AND "Product"."recipe" = FALSE)
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', "public"."stock_transaction"."created_at"), "Category"."name"
-- ORDER BY date_trunc('month', "public"."stock_transaction"."created_at") ASC, "Category"."name" ASC -- not needed here
) AS s
ORDER BY s."created_at"
```